# Java Hello World works on ubuntu, not on Cygwin

Tags: java, cygwin

So I am working on a simple Hello World for java, but the odd thing is that Hello World works on Ubuntu VM, but not on Cygwin.

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

I get this output on Cygwin:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/blUti.png]

While Ubuntu just outputs "Hello World!"

What is going on?

Answer (score 4):

You've somehow got an older version of `java` and a newer version of `javac` in your path.

The error means that the class has been compiled for a newer version of java than the one you're using.

Comment: So which one should I re-install? Java, Cygwin or both?

Comment: do a `which javac` and `which java` ... I'm wondering if you're picking up and old version of java from `/usr/bin` or something. You need to either change your path so that the new one is picked up first, or get rid of the older one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Java for cygwin.  You have Java for Windows installed.

You appear to have JRE 6 and JDK 7 in your path.  You need to remove Java 6 from your path and only use one version. You may need to check your Windows PATH as well. This is not a cygwin problem as such.